# merging edge between objects

Tags: modeling

I have three objects which I want to merge together.  At least I'd like to merge the edges on this face so it removes the awkward gap between the three objects.  No idea how to do this.   How can I merge the objects or the edges?

[image: three shapes intersecting]

Comment: Hello, so what problem are you meeting? Maybe share your file?

Comment: hi, I really just don't know how to do it.   I have highlighted the edges and not sure what to do next.  I tried going through the "edges" menu in edit mode. Tried a bunch of things.  Did the same with vertices.   Tried "dissolve edges" but that removes completely.  I just want to merge.

Comment: Press M while both edges are selected and select your desired merge option (Could be possible, that you need to switch to vertex mode)

Comment: have you joined the 3 objects into one (Ctrl J)?

Comment: That was it!    Select the edges and press M.  Merge by distance.   Thank you Thank you!